# Django RelatedManager - How to associate two querysets with one another?

Tags: django

New to Django so it's probable I'm doing this all wrong.

I have an `Album` class and a `Song` class. An `Album` can have many `Song`s. So far so simple.

Underneath my list of albums I want a list of their songs. Not every album has a song (don't ask) so I don't want to just query the `Song` model and join it to `Album`.

I've looked at [RelatedManager.add()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2//ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) but this doesn't do what I expect:

```
a = Album.objects.order_by('-release_date')[:5]
s = Song.objects.all()
a.release_set.add(s)
```

I get this error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'release_set'
```

Am I doing this right? As far as I can tell, I'm selecting a few `Album`s, selecting all the `Song`s, then attemtping to join the two collections together where they have a common `album_id`.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: AFAIK a must be an Album instance not a QuerySet/list get one Album and then add to it songs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, no. You've got the wrong end of the stick there somewhere.

`add` is for associating new Song items with their Album. If your songs have `album_id` values already,  they are already associated with their albums. You don't need to do anything specific to join them.

```
albums = Album.objects.order_by('-release_date')[:5]
for album in albums:
    print album.song_set.all()
```

Comment: Ah, so I get it for free at *both* ends, I see. I knew I could do that within `Song` since it had the explicit ManyToMany defined. Thanks, this does what I need!